# Temporary folder for pytest in Docker project testing is not being created

Tags: python, docker, pytest

The error is:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

The relevant code in *test_functions.py* is:

```
import urllib.request as urllib
import os
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from src.functions import save, write, query
import pytest

global spark

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("load_parquet") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/opt/spark/jars/postgresql-42.2.5.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def cache_dir(tmp_path_factory):
    return tmp_path_factory.mktemp("files") / "test.parquet"

def test_save(url='https://d37ci6vzurychx.cloudfront.net/trip-data/yellow_tripdata_2023-01.parquet', filename=cache_dir):
    print(cache_dir)
    assert save(url, filename), "Error saving file"

def test_write(write_method='psycopg2'):

    df = spark.read.parquet(cache_dir)
    if 'filename' not in df.columns:
        df = df.withColumn('filename', psf.lit('20-03'))

.....................
```

What am I doing wrong? I've spent many hours trying to make this work.

I've tried a few Google searches worth of pages and my different methods to make this work. None did. I was hoping to get the assert passed on the first, and if the second can read the file, it will pass as well.

The code ends with:

```
#%% Run tests
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(cache_dir)
    test_save()
    test_write()
    test_query()
    test_percentile()
    print("Everything passed")
# %%
```

After Magus's reply, test save is not working, and only *test_write* has an issue:

```
def test_write(cache_dir):
    write_method = 'psycopg2'
    url = 'https://d37ci6vzurychx.cloudfront.net/trip-data/yellow_tripdata_2023-01.parquet'
    save(url, cache_dir)

    df = spark.read.parquet(cache_dir)
    if 'filename' not in df.columns:
        df = df.withColumn('filename', psf.lit('20-03'))
```

```
2023-05-03 13:42:13 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
2023-05-03 13:42:13
2023-05-03 13:42:13 parameter = PosixPath('/tmp/pytest-of-root/pytest-0/files0/test.parquet')
2023-05-03 13:42:13 python_proxy_pool = <py4j.java_gateway.PythonProxyPool object at 0x7ff238c2b580>
2023-05-03 13:42:13
2023-05-03 13:42:13     def get_command_part(parameter, python_proxy_pool=None):
2023-05-03 13:42:13         """Converts a Python object into a string representation respecting the
2023-05-03 13:42:13         Py4J protocol.
2023-05-03 13:42:13
2023-05-03 13:42:13         For example, the integer `1` is converted to `u"i1"`
2023-05-03 13:42:13
2023-05-03 13:42:13         :param parameter: the object to convert
2023-05-03 13:42:13         :rtype: the string representing the command part
2023-05-03 13:42:13         """
2023-05-03 13:42:13         command_part = ""
2023-05-03 13:42:13
2023-05-03 13:42:13         if parameter is None:
2023-05-03 13:42:13             command_part = NULL_TYPE
2023-05-03 13:42:13         elif isinstance(parameter, bool):
2023-05-03 13:42:13             command_part = BOOLEAN_TYPE + smart_decode(parameter)
2023-05-03 13:42:13         elif isinstance(parameter, Decimal):
2023-05-03 13:42:13             command_part = DECIMAL_TYPE + smart_decode(parameter)
2023-05-03 13:42:13         elif isinstance(parameter, int) and parameter <= JAVA_MAX_INT\
2023-05-03 13:42:13                 and parameter >= JAVA_MIN_INT:
2023-05-03 13:42:13             command_part = INTEGER_TYPE + smart_decode(parameter)
2023-05-03 13:42:13         elif isinstance(parameter, long) or isinstance(parameter, int):
2023-05-03 13:42:13             command_part = LONG_TYPE + smart_decode(parameter)
2023-05-03 13:42:13         elif isinstance(parameter, float):
2023-05-03 13:42:13             command_part = DOUBLE_TYPE + encode_float(parameter)
2023-05-03 13:42:13         elif isbytearray(parameter):
2023-05-03 13:42:13             command_part = BYTES_TYPE + encode_bytearray(parameter)
2023-05-03 13:42:13         elif ispython3bytestr(parameter):
2023-05-03 13:42:13             command_part = BYTES_TYPE + encode_bytearray(parameter)
2023-05-03 13:42:13         elif isinstance(parameter, basestring):
2023-05-03 13:42:13             command_part = STRING_TYPE + escape_new_line(parameter)
2023-05-03 13:42:13         elif is_python_proxy(parameter):
2023-05-03 13:42:13             command_part = PYTHON_PROXY_TYPE + python_proxy_pool.put(parameter)
2023-05-03 13:42:13             for interface in parameter.Java.implements:
2023-05-03 13:42:13                 command_part += ";" + interface
2023-05-03 13:42:13         else:
2023-05-03 13:42:13 >           command_part = REFERENCE_TYPE + parameter._get_object_id()
2023-05-03 13:42:13 E           AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
2023-05-03 13:42:13
2023-05-03 13:42:13 /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py:298: AttributeError
2023-05-03 13:42:13 ----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
```

After some testing, it seems like there is some issue in the configuration for `spark` to use the temporary folders. Switching to Pandas to read the file in the folder worked.

Comment: You don't run your tests by calling the test functions directly. You run your tests by running `pytest` and have it run your tests; this is how you get fixtures and other pytest features to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you are doing wrong:

- Temporary folders are short-lived and are cleaned up after the process that is using it exits. You need to hold the *mktemp* context open using pytest's setup/teardown or *yield*
- fixtures are supposed to be declared in the test argument as a dependency.
- tests shouldn't be dependent between each other. Tests should either be stateless or create the desired state by using fixtures. In your case, you should have a fixture to create the file that the test_read is trying to access and not depend on the result of another test.

Using *yield* for the tmp_path fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def cache_dir(tmp_path_factory):
   #creates a context
   with tmp_path_factory.mktemp("files") as f
       #yields the file path, holds the context open
       yield f / "test.parquet"

def test_save(cache_dir):
    url='https://d37ci6vzurychx.cloudfront.net/trip-data/yellow_tripdata_2023-01.parquet'
    print(cache_dir)
    assert save(url,cache_dir), "Error saving file"
```

Comment: Thank you, test_save is now working, but I did edit test_write and it showing an error (ive edited post above) Also how would i go about doing the setup/teardown for this?